# Antlr4 different lexer rules using same symbols

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have the following grammar:

```
grammar Test2;

my_rule: 'start' L_PAREN dummy R_PAREN DOT;
dummy: upper_word|lower_word|single_quoted|distinct_object|dollar_word|dollar_dollar_word;

single_quoted               : SINGLE_QUOTE single_quoted_entry SINGLE_QUOTE;
single_quoted_entry         : SQ_CHAR+;

distinct_object             : DOUBLE_QUOTE distinct_object_entry DOUBLE_QUOTE ;
distinct_object_entry       : DO_CHAR+;

dollar_dollar_word          : DOLLAR DOLLAR lower_word; // make lower word token for the word
dollar_word                 : DOLLAR lower_word; // make lower word token for the word
upper_word                  : UPPER_WORD; // necessary since it should be one token
UPPER_WORD                  : UPPER_ALPHA ALPHA_NUMERIC*;
lower_word                  : LOWER_WORD; // necessary since it should be one token
LOWER_WORD                  : LOWER_ALPHA ALPHA_NUMERIC*;

DOLLAR                      : '$';
L_PAREN                     : '(';
R_PAREN                     : ')';
L_SQUARE_BRACKET            : '[';
R_SQUARE_BRACKET            : ']';
COMMA                       : ',';
VLINE                       : '|';
STAR                        : '*';
PLUS                        : '+';
ARROW                       : '>';
LESS_SIGN                   : '<';
DOT                         : '.';
UNDERSCORE                  : '_';

NUMERIC                     : [0-9];
LOWER_ALPHA                 : [a-z];
UPPER_ALPHA                 : [A-Z];
ALPHA_NUMERIC               : LOWER_ALPHA
                            | UPPER_ALPHA
                            | NUMERIC
                            | UNDERSCORE;

DOUBLE_QUOTE                : '"';
DO_CHAR                     : [\u0028-\u0029\u002B-\u0085\u0087-\u00B0]; // for double_quoted
SINGLE_QUOTE                : '\'' ;
SQ_CHAR                     : [\u0028-\u002E\u0032-\u0085\u0087-\u00B0]; // for single_quoted

NEWLINE                     : '\r'? '\n' -> skip;
WS                          : [ \t]+ -> skip;
```

Starting out with my_rule the dummy rule works entering an upper_word, lower_word, dollar_word, dollar_dollar_word.
However single_quoted and distinct_object wont work because they expect SQ_CHAR+ or DO_CHAR+ which also cover already defined tokens such as UPPER_ALPHA among many others.

A solution would be to add all defined tokens with a pipe to the place where SQ_CHAR/DO_CHAR are used. This may look similar to this but with way more pipes:

```
single_quoted               : SINGLE_QUOTE single_quoted_entry SINGLE_QUOTE;
single_quoted_entry         : (SQ_CHAR|UPPER_ALPHA|...way more tokens here...)+;
```

The same again for double_quoted. Since this is a tedious task to check for all ascii codes which are already defined as tokens and it is error-prone when changing the grammar some simpler solution would be advantageous.

Are there any simple solutions?

Comment: You'll have to rework your grammar: ANTLR uses separate lexing and parsing phases, the parser can't tell the lexer *"now give me a `SQ_CHAR` please"*, the lexer already did its job th this point. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/antlr/3271/lexer-rules-in-v4/11235/priority-rules#t=201610271857077831824) for the priority rules. Try to minimize your rule count, make them as simple as possible, and then do a separate validation pass on the parser's output, using a visitor for instance.

Comment: You are right of course that the goal is minimizing. Unfortunately this grammar is an excerpt from a huge grammar which I cannot alter easily and the definitions of the words with and without quotation marks using their specific character range are absolutely necessary. I found a solution which will do the job but not create extra leafs for the quotation marks which is shown below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another solution which is applicable because i do not use the single quote and the double quote somewhere else in the grammar.

Creating lexer tokens including the quotation marks works:

```
grammar Test2;

my_rule: 'start' L_PAREN dummy R_PAREN DOT;
dummy: upper_word|lower_word|single_quoted|distinct_object|dollar_word|dollar_dollar_word;

single_quoted               : SINGLE_QUOTED;
SINGLE_QUOTED               : SINGLE_QUOTE SQ_CHAR+ SINGLE_QUOTE;
distinct_object             : DISTINCT_OBJECT;
DISTINCT_OBJECT             : DOUBLE_QUOTE DO_CHAR+ DOUBLE_QUOTE;

dollar_dollar_word          : DOLLAR DOLLAR lower_word; // make lower word token for the word
dollar_word                 : DOLLAR lower_word; // make lower word token for the word
upper_word                  : UPPER_WORD; // necessary since it should be one token
UPPER_WORD                  : UPPER_ALPHA ALPHA_NUMERIC*;
lower_word                  : LOWER_WORD; // necessary since it should be one token
LOWER_WORD                  : LOWER_ALPHA ALPHA_NUMERIC*;

DOLLAR                      : '$';
L_PAREN                     : '(';
R_PAREN                     : ')';
L_SQUARE_BRACKET            : '[';
R_SQUARE_BRACKET            : ']';
COMMA                       : ',';
VLINE                       : '|';
STAR                        : '*';
PLUS                        : '+';
ARROW                       : '>';
LESS_SIGN                   : '<';
DOT                         : '.';
UNDERSCORE                  : '_';

NUMERIC                     : [0-9];
LOWER_ALPHA                 : [a-z];
UPPER_ALPHA                 : [A-Z];
ALPHA_NUMERIC               : LOWER_ALPHA
                            | UPPER_ALPHA
                            | NUMERIC
                            | UNDERSCORE;

DOUBLE_QUOTE                : '"';
DO_CHAR                     : [\u0028-\u0029\u002B-\u0085\u0087-\u00B0]; // for double_quoted
SINGLE_QUOTE                : '\'' ;
SQ_CHAR                     : [\u0028-\u002E\u0032-\u0085\u0087-\u00B0]; // for single_quoted

NEWLINE                     : '\r'? '\n' -> skip;
WS                          : [ \t]+ -> skip;
```

The positions of SINGLE_QUOTED, DISTINCT_OBJECT, UPPER_WORD and LOWER_WORD are indifferent (tested).

Note that this solution will not create extra leafs for the quotation marks.